# What does zsh's magic-space command do?

Tags: zsh

I found the following command in my `.zshrc`, probably copied from some website:

```
bindkey " " magic-space # do history expansion on space
```

The manpages are about as helpful as the very succinct comment:

```
magic-space
    Perform history expansion and insert a space into the buffer. [...]
```

So what does `magic-space` actually do? Under which circumstances can I see this history expansion in action?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`magic-space` performs [history expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion): if you type a space after a command that starts with `!` (or `^`) to refer to (part of) a previous command, that history reference is expanded. If you just type a space, the history reference is expanded when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
$ zsh -f
% echo hello
hello
% !1 world
echo hello world
hello world
% bindkey " " magic-space
% !1
```

At this point, press <kbd>Space</kbd>, and the line turns to

```
% echo hello ¡
```

where `¡` represents the posititon of the cursor.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious for most users of the shell, but I had to go looking for this property. It was set in `.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh` with some misleading comment: `bindkey ' ' magic-space # [Space] - don't do history expansion`