# How do I prevent zsh from expanding shell history when I press space?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I can reproduce this issue on cygwin and Ubuntu wsl's oh-my-zsh shell, but my bash shell works the way I want. My intent is to run these two lines on the command line:

```bash
npm rm plugin-alias
npm i -D plugin-alias
```

Here are a series of commands I typed into zsh in an attempt to achieve that:

```bash
$ npm rm plugin-alias
$ ^rm^i # when I pressed space, it auto completed to:
npm i  plugin-alias # and my cursor was placed at the end of the line. 
# I `ctrl+c`'d to try other ideas
$ ^rm^'i\ # when I pressed space...
npm i  plugin-alias # this auto completed the same as above. 
# I `ctrl+c`'d to try other ideas
$ ^rm^'i -D'
npm 'i -D' plugin-alias # this auto completed to surround the argument in single quotes. Same issue with double quotes.
```

I tried some other [Event Designators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243368/101311) like `!!s:/rm/i -D/...`, but it auto expanded the same way. This leads me to believe there is a oh-my-zsh setting doing this. If I'm right about that, what's it called and how do I turn it off? I'd be okay with tab behaving this way, but not spaces.

Comment: Have you tried adding `setopt HIST_VERIFY=true` into your`~/.zshrc`?

Comment: @Farzan When I tried, it gave me an error: `no such option: HIST_VERIFY=true`

Comment: Sorry. May be `setopt NO_HIST_VERIFY` instead.

Comment: @Farzan `setopt NO_HIST_VERIFY` didn't error (`setopt NO_HIST_VERIFY=true` said no such option), but it didn't change the behavior as far as I could tell.

Comment: Seems to be [what zle's magic-space command does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47349)

Comment: @rowboat that was it. I'll accept that as an answer